# devise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::SessionsController#new error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm a new to rails so I'm still learning some concepts.

I installed the ruby gem devise to help with adding users/database etc..
I'm getting an error when  I'm trying to access paths provided by devise.

The URL for my page is

> https://rubypractice-minhaja.c9users.io

And for example if I try to access

> https://rubypractice-minhaja.c9users.io//users/sign_in

I get the same error mentioned in my title I've tried for a long time to look up for a solution but I'm yet to find one.

I did check rails routes and all the routes are there so I'm not sure what the issue is.

> https://github.com/minhajahmed1/event_platform

Above is the link to my `github` if that helps. I would really appreciate any help I get, thanks.

Comment: share your routes and user model and user migration

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$ rails generate devise MODEL
```

Was just an example, if you read the instructions you should have replaced "MODEL" with your model name "User"

```
$ rails generate devise User
```

Comment: Thanks, so how do i go about fixing this? I ran did rails db:rollback and then ran rails generate devise User, however when I run rails db:migrate I get an error.

Comment: "I get an error" is probably the least helpful thing you could say.  If you could modify your question to outline the exact error you're getting then you could get some useful responses.  Try the rollback again `rake db:rollback` in case the migration went through partially, , then make sure that you delete the "wrong" migration in `/db/migrate` and delete the `app/models/model,db` file` and that should put you into a good state, so you can try then try 'rake db:migrate` again.